# Making a multivariable Function continuous

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

This function

$$f(x,y)=\frac{e^{xy}-\cos (x)+\sin(xy)}{x}$$

can be made continous for $f(0,y)$ by defining

$$f(0, y) = 2y .$$

My question is: how can i get to this conclusion ("$2y$ must be it") on my own?

I have tried using limits, substituting $u=xy$,... or polar, but no luck. Is there a list somewhere of things to try?

Any help very appreciated.

Comment: ... and those who don't like l'Hospital's rule write
$$f(x,y)= y\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}+\frac{x}{1+\cos x}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}+y\frac{\sin xy}{xy}.$$

Comment: @njguliyev that is very nice. if you add it as an answer i will +1

Comment: @njguliyev i know your terms are correct and understand how you got to the $$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}+y\frac{\sin xy}{xy}$$ but how did you get to the first part? could you describe (briefly) as an answer?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Comment: @njguliyev thanks! will +1 both answers as soon as i have 15 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $y \ne 0$, we see from L'Hospital's rule that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x; y) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{y e^{xy} - \sin{x} + y \cos{xy}}{1} = \frac{y - 0 + y}{1} = 2y$$

Comment: I thought that L'H is not allowed in multivariable problems, but i guess after getting the 2y we can somehow prove that this is indeed continuous?

Comment: @ben Since I've fixed $y$, it's just a one variable function. This is why I've written $f(x; y)$ instead of $f(x, y)$. This is just meant to show why the limit must be $2y$, not to formally prove it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method without using l'Hospital's rule:
$$f(x,y) = \frac{(e^{xy}- 1) +(1 -\cos x) + \sin xy}{x} = \frac{e^{xy}-1}{x} + \frac{1-\cos^2 x}{x(1 +\cos x)} + \frac{\sin xy}{x} = y\frac{e^{xy}-1}{xy}+\frac{x}{1+\cos x}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2}+y\frac{\sin xy}{xy}.$$

Comment: nice. all terms go to 0 or 1y. obviously we like to have terms like $\frac{e^t}{t}$ and the others. I wonder if there is a method on how to choose the transformations or is it intuition?

Comment: The method is to try to get well-known limits like $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}$ or $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}$ by transforming the initial expression. Of course, this doesn't always work or at least not so easily. In those cases you have to use other methods.